# select columns based on input

Tags: mysql, pdo

hi there am having problem in solving this query. Before i posted a similar question but got no response. So am posting as simple as i can.

here is my table room_rate

```
   room id    single_room   double_room  triple-room
   1          150           200          250
   2          300           400          450
```

what i want to do is select single_room or double_room based on user input.
here is my form

```
   <form action="test3.php" method="GET">
   <select name="roomtype">
   <option value="s">Single</option>
   <option value="d">Double</option>
   <option value="t">Triple</option>
   </select>
   <button type="Submit">Button</button>
   </form>
```

here is my code

```
   $sql = "select case
   when roomtype = 's' then single_room END AS RoomRates
   from room_rate where roomtype = ?";
   $Info_stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $Info_stmt->execute(array($_GET['roomtype']));
   $Info = $Info_stmt->fetch();
```

can any one suggest me the code to do this in Mysql. maybe my whole code is wrong.

Comment: that's why variables are created

Comment: Do you have any script for connecting to the database? If yes, then how do you access it?

Comment: what does your PHP mysql lookup look like so far? (I'm assuming php since you tagged this PDO). Provide existing code.

Comment: there i have pasted the code.. i would appreciate your help

Comment: Your MySQL syntax is terribly wrong! Try a simpler approach, as I feel your table and data structure is very simple!

Comment: could you please hint me how to make it 'SIMPLE'

Comment: `SELECT * from room_rate;` .. then using if else based on `$_GET['roomtype']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your test3.php, you can run something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['roomtype'])){
    $roomtype = $_GET['roomtype'];
    if($roomtype == 's'){
        $sql = "SELECT room_id, single_room FROM room_rate";
    }
    //Do a similar else if for rest 2 room types
}
```

As a matter of fact, you need to execute this query just once:
`SELECT * from room_rate;`

You can then display data as `if else` conditions based on your `$_GET` variable.

Comment: what do you think about my code above? can i make use of case when then?

Comment: You're using `roomtype = 's'` without getting the variable first. Also, it is supposed to be `$roomtype` if at all you're comparing. It's actually not a proper way to do it. You can do it in a more simpler way as I mentioned.